# Freeman chain - cvApproxChains (openCV)- Example

Tags: opencv

everyone

i'm new to opencv i came across the Freeman chain - cvApproxChains algorithms

have searched for some intoduction code on how to use the method (cvApproxChains) but invain

HOPE someone has already implemented such a method and is ready to share his knowledge + hard work

thanks in advance hoping to get a response sooon

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code to get started:

```
{
    string inputFile = "path/to/your/file.bmp";
    // Create Memory Storage
    CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    //Load image from disk
    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(inputFile.c_str(),0);

    //Create contour chains
    CvSeq *seq = 0;
    cvFindContours(img, storage, &seq, sizeof(CvContour),
        CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_CODE, cvPoint(0,0) );

    //Create approximated Freeman chains
    seq = cvApproxChains(seq, storage, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,0,0,0);
    printf("total: %i\n",seq->total);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: please avoid answering questions from 2012. also the whole c-api is deprecated, and should no more be used. (or even be recommended here)

Comment: For what I needed (and what this guy asked), this worked just fine :) Thanks for review anyway!